# AngularJS: How exactly does $route work?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

This is an interview question I was asked: AngularJS: How exactly does the $route service work?

From what I understand, $route loads the template upon link/button/whatever clicking, then replaces the [ng-view] div/section with the template's HTML, stores it in memory, and swipes out subsequent clicks with the template in memory.

Is this correct or does Angular load the template every time a click is received?

In other words, does Angular load the template once or does it load every time? It seems to me it would be more efficient to load it only once but I don't know that for certain. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular documentation for [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) says

> The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache
>   for quick retrieval

Angular $route uses $templateCache internally, so yes, the template is loaded once and reused from the cache on subsequent visits to the same route.

This [blog post](https://blog.logentries.com/2015/03/template-caching-in-angular-how-to-avoid-the-storm/) has more information. Relevant bits:

> the first time the template is accessed, angular will get it from the
>   server and add it to the $templateCache
>
> every time that ID is referenced from then on, angular gets it from
>   the $templateCache and not from the server!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your answer is necessarily wrong, as much as there are many parts to a page rendering/how it is rendered ($route, $routeProvider, ngView directive)

> $route is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML partials). It watches $location.url() and tries to map the path to an existing route definition.

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) or dig into the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L254)

EDIT: Added explanation.